# How to get sub-folder names from a given path Server.MapPath

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, subdirectory

I want get the folder names from `server.MapPath` in ASP.NET MVC 3 application.
In this action, I have to check (if there exist more folders in a given folder name) if a .jpg file is in that folder and if so, return that folder.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("Content/");
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = dInfo.GetDirectories();

if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    // This path is a directory
    ar.Add(path);
    //ProcessDirectory(path);
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response  i have tried to get folders but i didn't get the solution and i have post my code in my Query please check it once..and give any suggetion please

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I've understand the qestion correctly, but I think you want something like

```
string path = Server.MapPath(YOURPATH);
List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

or something like

```
string path = Server.MapPath(YOURPATH);
List<string> picFolders = new List<string>();

if(Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg").Length > 0)
    picFolders.Add(path)

foreach(string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if(Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg").Length > 0)
        picFolders.Add(dir)
}
```

Comment: Hi i am trying ur code but it showing error like " Could not find a part of the path 'D:\victor\Pivot\Ilifelooks\Ilifelooks\Ilifelooks\Gallery\Content\'. "

Comment: Does the Path 'D:\victor\Pivot\Ilifelooks\Ilifelooks\Ilifelooks\Gallery\Content\' exist?

Comment: yes it is exist in my server path in that folder some images also exist.